# undefined reference to `Person::customerIDChanged(QString const&)'

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

I am begginer to blackberry development.I was creating a simple Person class having .cpp and .hpp files with firstName ,customerId, address as members of class.I had created Properties and setters,getters ,but it is giving error in Person.cpp , Setters definition,when i try to emit the signals which are declared in Person.hpp.

Error : undefined reference to `Person::customerIDChanged(QString const&)'

Person.cpp:

```
void Person::setCustomerID(const QString &newId)
{
    if (newId != m_id) {
        m_id = newId;
        emit customerIDChanged(newId); // gives error at this line
    }
}

void Person::setFirstName(const QString &newName)
{
    if (newName != m_firstName) {
        m_firstName = newName;
        emit firstNameChanged(newName);// gives error at this line
                }
}
void Person::setAddress(const QString &newName){

if (newName != m_address) {
 m_address = newName;
 emit addressChanged(m_address);// gives error at this line
   }}
```

Person.hpp:

```
class Person:public QObject
{ 
    Q_OBJECT

Q_PROPERTY( QString customerID READ customerID WRITE setCustomerID NOTIFY customerIDChanged FINAL)

   Q_PROPERTY( QString firstName READ firstName WRITE setFirstName NOTIFY firstNameChanged FINAL)

   Q_PROPERTY( QString address READ address WRITE setAddress NOTIFY addressChanged FINAL)

public:

  Person(QObject *parent = 0): QObject(parent){};

  Person(const QString &id, const QString &firstname, const QString &address, QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
   , m_id(id)
   , m_firstName(firstname)
   , m_address(address){};

  QString customerID() const;
  QString firstName() const;
  QString address() const;

  void setCustomerID(const QString &newId);
  void setFirstName(const QString &newName);
  void setAddress(const QString &newName);

Q_SIGNALS:

void customerIDChanged(const QString &newId);
void firstNameChanged(const QString &firstName);
void addressChanged(const QString &address);

private:

    QString m_id;
    QString m_firstName;
    QString m_address;};
#endif
```

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: Shouldn't the MOC files generate that reference? Did you build your project with qmake?

Comment: yes, i have build my project with qmake only!

Comment: MOC should be generating a moc_person.cpp file. Can you verify it?

Comment: where should i look for that moc file..? i couldnot find it ? can anybody help me?

Comment: When building with Momentics, they are generated here: ``$BUILDDIR/arm/o.le-v7-g/.moc/`` in debug, and ``$BUILDDIR/arm/o.le-v7/.moc/`` in release.

Comment: my c++ is not great, but should the signals have "const" on the parameters?  Compared with my own app where I emit signals I am not using const and it works fine.